# Where is the syntax error in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

The following is my webhooks_controller.rb:

```
class WebhooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :auth_anybody!
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def tx
    if params[:type] == "transaction" && params[:hash].present?
      AMQPQueue.enqueue(:deposit_coin, txid: params[:hash], channel_key: "satoshi")
      render :json => { :status => "queued" }
  end
end
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
webhooks_controller.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Everything look ok. Where could my error be?

Comment: You forgot to `end` the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `end` of the `if` clause. Right code is

```
def tx
  if params[:type] == "transaction" && params[:hash].present?
    AMQPQueue.enqueue(:deposit_coin, txid: params[:hash], channel_key: "satoshi")
    render :json => { :status => "queued" }
  end
end
```